# How to compare if 2 string vales are the same

Tags: c#, arrays, string

How do i compare if 2 string values are the same in an array?

For e.g. 
If someone enter `Apple, Orange, Banana, Apple`
and I want to check the number of unique values.

Only Orange and Banana is unique here so the result of this will be 2.

Comment: Do you want to compare two strings, or find unique ones in an array?

Comment: what it will return if the array is like: `Apple, Orange, Banana, Orange, Cherry, Orange, Apple` ? 2? 3? 4? I think you have a semantic error here.

Comment: your question is not clear and what did you try? where is your code?

Comment: there will be banana and cherry only, and number of unique item is 2

Comment: Okay now I get what you ask.

Comment: OK, you want to count the singletons.

Comment: Okay assume that i do not know what the user input for the fruits, how do i check if using a for loop ?

Comment: You need to edit this question and make it clear. Given what you've written so far, it could either be that you want the answer to be `2` because there are two instances of the string "Apple", or it could be that you want the answer to be `2` because there are two instances of strings that are not duplicated (i.e. "Orange" and "Banana"). Either is easy to do, but no one can tell what you actually want.

Comment: So with a little editing, this question could have become a legit one, but people put it on hold :)

Comment: `var query = fruit.GroupBy(f => f).Where(g => g.Count() == 1).Select(g => g.Key);`

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a count of the unique values, you can use the `.Distinct()` method:

```
List<string> fruits = new List<string>{ "Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Apple"};
int numberOfUniqueFruits = fruits.Distinct().Count();
```

To get the items that only occur once, you can get those whose .Count() == 1:

```
var uniqueFruits = fruits.Where(n => fruits.Count(f => f == n) == 1).ToList();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return 3? OP said it should return 2 :/

Comment: And according to the question requirements this answer is wrong.

Comment: @RufusL reread the question again and test your code. You get 3 the OP wants 2

Comment: Ahh, I see, you are right...

Comment: Added code to address that problem

Comment: Yes, this should be the answer. (barring other problems with case)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var x = new string[]
        {
            "Apple",
            "Orange",
            "Banana",
            "Apple"
        };

        var i = x.GroupBy(c => c.ToUpper()).Select(c => new {c, count = c.Count()}).Count(c => c.count == 1);

        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Remove `.ToUpper()`  if you want to check by case sensitivity.

Comment: Also this answer is wrong. You get 3 while the op askes for 2

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ check before comment please

Comment: Use the OP values please. or add to your input "xyz"